Where do i store my jwt for authorization?
I searched many article for days i find they sending the token like this
res.json({token})
and using a middleware like this
function verifyToken(req, res, next){
  const authHeader = req.headers['authorization']
  const token = authHeader && authHeader.split(' ')[1]

  if (token == null) return res.sendStatus(401); // No token provided

  if(jwt.verify(token,process.env.JWT_SECRET)){
    next()
  }
}

How do they put that token in the req.headers['authorization']
when i console.log that it gives me only undefined
the res.json({token}) only send me to the token

I'm suspecting you're working on client side to send token to server side, the best way to actually store token in real production level is to put in Cookie with Httponly flag and set your domain in the cookie.
If your website is vulnerable to any security, then using LocalStorage  your website will be vulnerable to token theft and that's the worst you'd want to happen.
There's article that explain how to achieve that: https://www.saurabhmisra.dev/store-jwt-token-http-only-cookie/

thank you i been searching around about 2 days for this

They basically setting the token in client side LocalStorage, and when sending any request from the client side they using any interceptor (to make it easy, exp: axios interceptor) or defining the header object like :
    fetch('https://reqbin.com/echo/get/json', {
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
   'authorization': `Bearer ${localStorage.getItem('token')}`

  }
})
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => console.log(JSON.stringify(data)))


where do i put this part? in my nodejs app

this part is when you're fetching data from client side js
